# Best DB structure for Organisations/Locations/Departments/Users?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, join, database-design

I'm building a system in which we should have a database containing organisations, locations, departments, and users. They are connected as you would expect:

- each organisation can contain one or more locations
- each location (building) can contain one or more departments
- at each department work one or more users
- a user can work at more than one department

BUT: a department can span accross more than one location.

Intuitively I would create the DB as follows:
[image: circle]
The problem with the structure you see above is the BUT; it isn't possible to have one department which spans accross two locations. I figured that that isn't really a problem, because I can simply create the same department for two locations. And if there's an admin for this department I can simply make him admin at the two locations.

One programmer suggested a different structure though:

[image: tree]
He's a big fan of this structure because he says it is way more flexible to span anything accross anything. My problem with it is that it's less readable when manually reading the database, plus I would be more confused when working on the code.

My question is; which structure would you prefer? What is the big plus for this last structure? Is this used more often? All tips are welcome!

Comment: So what I am reading is that you have one structure that works, but may be a little harder to read, and one that does not work and you are asking which one we like better... Go with the one that works

Comment: @SaggingRufus - Well, the first one is in my opinion way more readable and has one downside which in my opinion is not really a problem in practice, while the other one might cater for all possibilities, but makes things very complicated. My question is; is the second DB design used a lot, or is it some kind of obscure idea of that programmer?

Comment: @kramer65 I've never seen the second design. Maybe that's because (if the yellow keys are the primary keys then) it's not even in normal form (there are too many foreign keys f.ex.).

Comment: If a department can span two locations and vice versa, then simply create a `department_location` table with both ids as a composite unique key (e.g. the primary key). And I'm not sure what the `organization_id` is in the users table, at least that relation isn't listed in your requirements. Even assuming the 4 columns form the primary key together, your second model is plain wrong. It e.g. says: locations can be owns by several organizations, and a user can work for a department in location 1 but not the same department at location 2. Unless that describes the reality, don't do that.

Comment: @pozs: "it's not even in normal form (there are too many foreign keys" -- are you saying it violates first normal form or a higher normal form? If higher, which one? I don't know what you mean by "too many foreign keys" though.

Comment: I would expect a table to model the relationship *from* an organization *to* its departments; another *from* department *to* its locations; the relationship *from* organization *to* its locations would then be implied by these two tables, rather than being explicitly modelled using a table.

Comment: @onedaywhen the 2NF, f.ex. the `users` have an `organization_id`, but `junction` table also connects them. And there are many more. Also, the attributes in the simple tables suggest that everything belongs to an organization, while the `junction` table suggests that it is the `users` table where everyone else belong to. Maybe that's just the image, which is poorly drawn.

Comment: The way you have it designed, a department and an organization are completely independent of each other. Wouldn't an organization be made up of one or more departments?

Comment: @onedaywhen - in your setup, how are users linked? Because if they are linked to departments, you don't know at which location they work.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: Organizations have multiple departments, departments have multiple locations, users work for one department in one of that department's locations.

Here's my quick sketch:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
( user_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE Organizations
( org_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE Departments
( dep_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE Locations
( loc_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE OrgDepartments
( org_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE 
     REFERENCES Organizations ( org_id ),
  dep_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
     REFERENCES Departments ( dep_id ) );

CREATE TABLE DepartmentLocations
( dep_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
     REFERENCES OrgDepartments( dep_id ),
  loc_id INTEGER NOT NULL
     REFERENCES Locations ( loc_id ),
  UNIQUE ( loc_id, dep_id ) );

CREATE TABLE UserLocations
( user_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
     REFERENCES Users ( user_id ),
  dep_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  loc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ( loc_id, dep_id )
     REFERENCES DepartmentLocations ( loc_id, dep_id ) );
```

Comment: Looks quite nice this. And if a user works on a departement for more than one location the user simply gets multiple records in the UserLocations table?

Comment: @kramer65 Yes but you'd need to change the key to accommodate this e.g. `( dep_id, user_id )`